# Access attributes of asp.net controls from JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

how can i access to tooptip of textbox using jquery ?!!
or any asp control attribute !!

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="myclass" ID="Name" runat="server" ToolTip="some tooltip">/asp:TextBox>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
        $('.myclass').click(function() {
                alert($(this).attr('ToolTip'));
           });
});
```

or just set my control to HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToolTip` attributes convert to `title` attributes in HTML. Try the following:

```
 alert($(this).attr("title"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $(function () {
        $('.mybutton').onclick(function () {
            var tooltip = "B";
            $('.mytb').attr('title', tooltip);
        });
    });

  <button type="button" CssClass="mybutton">Click Me!</button> 
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ToolTip="A" CssClass="mytb"></asp:TextBox>
```